# Does bitcoin-js have a method to check unspent transaction status?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet, blockcypher

How does [BlockCypher explorer](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/mitTmNgXyoEANondxZns8dS6GcXTzVhJW6/) get data about spent or unspent transaction status?

[image]

Does `bitcoin-js` library have some methods for it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `bitcoin-js` lib, but Blockcypher has API method:

```js
const fetch = require('cross-fetch')

const getAddress = async address => {
  const url = `https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/addrs/${address}`
  const res = await fetch(url)

  return await res.json()
}

getAddress('mitTmNgXyoEANondxZns8dS6GcXTzVhJW6')
  .then(({txrefs}) => txrefs.filter(tx => tx.spent === false))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

and you'll get sth like this

```
[ { tx_hash: 'bdbd9253b052cb17afdf42c006c69f6d9f7513d2176db1c088fdbd2381edf2de',
    block_height: 1519165,
    tx_input_n: -1,
    tx_output_n: 1,
    value: 15800000,
    ref_balance: 32343852,
    spent: false, // @docs tx status
    confirmations: 60,
    confirmed: '2019-05-31T20:43:22Z',
    double_spend: false },
  { tx_hash: '4014e09c48ec4de6c4f1e82b38107f4ca77037e96e4989abe5ba5cf459d57700',
    block_height: 1519149,
    tx_input_n: -1,
    tx_output_n: 1,
    value: 10000,
    ref_balance: 17044852,
    spent: false, // @docs tx status
    confirmations: 76,
    confirmed: '2019-05-31T18:43:02Z',
    double_spend: false } ]
```